# MYSQL Inserting Data Into Table Using Indexed Table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to insert the data from one table to another table if someone submits an ID that is indexed in the two tables.

For example:

I have Table A with: `ID | First Name | Last Name | Course`

and Table B has: `ID | Name | Course`

Table A has data: `32 | John | Doe | IT`

And Table B will receive its data from a Form that a user will input.

How do I automatically insert the First Name and Last Name column from Table A into Table B if the user inputs #32 on the form as well which is indexed with Table A ID column?

I'm trying to use the normal *Insert Into* and Selecting the table columns for the Values of the name but it doesn't seem to read it.

```
$upload = "INSERT INTO `TableB` ( `ID`, `Name`, `Course`) VALUES ('$id','(SELECT FirstName FROM TableA WHERE ID = '$borrow_id'),' '$course');";
```

I was thinking that maybe I can select the ID from the submitted form and if there is a similar data in Table A, it will get the other data from it and insert it into Table B.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is almost there, you just got the syntax wrong. You can use an `INSERT..SELECT` statement on TableB selecting the data you want from TableA, so it should look something like this:

```php
<?php

$upload = "INSERT INTO `TableB` ( `ID`, `Name`, `Course`) SELECT $id, FirstName, $course FROM TableA WHERE ID = '$borrow_id;";
```

To test, you can just copy the `SELECT` part of your query and execute on your database to see if the data is correct. Keep in mind that this statement should have the exact number of columns in your insert and be in the same order.